this.form.controls['user'].addControl is not a function
I am trying to add a new control to my FormGroup but I get the error: this.form.controls['user'].addControl is not a function.
Here is my code:
this.form.addControl('user', new FormGroup([]));
(<FormGroup>this.form.controls['user']).addControl(
   'john', this.formBuilder.control(''),{ emitEvent: false }
 );

When I check this.form.controls['user'] instanceof FormGroup I get false!
I am using the same principle in another component, and there I get no error.
Also this code was working on angular 16, and after upgrading to angular 18, I see this error.
Does anyone have any idea what can be the problem and how can be solved?

FormGroup is strictly typed, so your formGroup actually has type of FormGroup<[]>.
It's better to use FormRecord, FormGroup with optional controls or UntypedFormGroup for your scenario (docs).
However, if you want to go your own way, here's a working option:
((this.form as FormGroup).controls['user'] as FormGroup).addControl(
  'john', this.formBuilder.control(''),{ emitEvent: false }
);


Thanks @Tortila, the problem was solved by changing addControl  to setControl!
